# ng-repeat not displaying but will console.log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am running into an issue with my angular app where an array that I am trying to `ng-repeat` onto the view will log in the console but will not display on the page.

This is my function in my controller

```
    var calCells = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar-cell');
    for(i = 0; i < calCells.length; i++){
        calCells[i].addEventListener('click', updateDay, false);
    }
    var todayCell = document.getElementsByClassName('today');
    todayCell[0].addEventListener('click',updateDay,false);
    } // renderCalender function ends

    function displayDayPosts(selectedDay) {
        $scope.displayDay = happyService.setDisplayPosts(selectedDay);
        console.log($scope.displayDay);
    }  

    var updateDay = function(){
        var thisCellTime = this.querySelector('time');
        var selectedDate = thisCellTime.getAttribute('datetime');
        //onclick text//
        displayDayPosts(selectedDate);
        console.log(selectedDate)
    }
```

This is where I am getting the object in my factory

```
function setDisplayPosts(selectedDay) {
    var days = getDays();
    var day = {posts: []};
    for(i=0; i < days.length; i++){
        if(selectedDay.substring(0,10) === days[i].date.substring(0,10)){
            day.newAvg = days[i].average;

            days[i].forEach(function(post){

                var postObj = {};
                postObj.mood = post.mood;
                postObj.comment = post.comment;
                postObj.rating = post.rating;
                postObj.date = post.date;
                day.posts.push(postObj);

            });

        }
    }
    return day;
}
```

And here is how I am displaying it on the page

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in displayDay.posts track by $index" class="entry">
    <h4 class="entry-title">{{entry.date | date }}</h4>
    <p class="rating-display"><strong>Rating:</strong> {{entry.rating}}</p>
    <p class="comment-display"><strong>Comment:</strong> {{entry.comment}}</p>
    <p class="moods-display"><strong>Moods:</strong> {{entry.mood}}</p>
</div>
```

The object displayDay is logging as I expected in the console.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank!

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons why the array in the ng-repeat might be empty. Can you show how the controller is set up? What is the full html before that repeat? Is displayDay already available in the page? Normally you would expect to see it accessed via a controller reference, like $ctrl.displayDay. What is displayed if you put a {{displayDay}} before the repeat div?

Comment: Please show the console output?